# Wordpress theme customizer - can't add section/settings

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the Worpdress theme customizer by adding sections and settings but no matter what I add in my functions.php file, nothing ever shows up in the customizer.

Example:

```
function starter_customize_register( $wp_customize ) 
{
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'mytheme_new_section_name' , array(
    'title'      => __( 'Visible Section Name', 'starter' ),
    'priority'   => 30, ) );    
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'starter_customize_register');
```

I would have expected this to add a section with the chosen name but the only things I see are the two initial sections from Wordpress (site title & tagline, static front page).

I had found a pretty nice tutorial here (http://code.tutsplus.com/series/a-guide-to-the-wordpress-theme-customizer--wp-33722). I followed every step and even took their example theme but there again, no new sections or settings are displayed.

Makes me wonder if something is wrong with my configuration.

I'm using a wordpress network/multisite, don't know if that's relevant.

Any idea?

Thanks
Laurent

Comment: one additional remark: themes like twentyfifteen, twentyforteen,... are working fine, customization works for those.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to add setting(s) and control(s) to make it work:

```
function starter_customize_register( $wp_customize ) 
{
    $wp_customize->add_section( 'starter_new_section_name' , array(
        'title'    => __( 'Visible Section Name', 'starter' ),
        'priority' => 30
    ) );   

    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'starter_new_setting_name' , array(
        'default'   => '#000000',
        'transport' => 'refresh',
    ) );

    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Color_Control( $wp_customize, 'link_color', array(
        'label'    => __( 'Header Color', 'starter' ),
        'section'  => 'starter_new_section_name',
        'settings' => 'starter_new_setting_name',
    ) ) );
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'starter_customize_register');
```

Reference: [Theme Customization API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not realise settings and controls had to be there as well before something showed up in the customizer.

Comment: Note that `add_setting` must be called before `add_control`. I first listed those two functions the other way around (`add_control` above `add_setting`), and that didn't work.

Comment: I wish the official documentation had an example like this.